# Difference between similar terms in OS and GPU

Tags: operating-system, gpu, theory

I encountered the term thread in abstraction in OS which means a piece of code which can be executed independently and kernel that it performs the crucial tasks of the OS. But recently, I encountered the same term in Parallelization of Programs related course in reference with GPU's. Where thread are something physical in GPU's i guess and kernel I couldn't get. If there is any difference, It would be great to learn about that!

I tried looking up online but couldn't find more than articles related to such terms in OS. I was expecting a comparison with a example or working maybe.

Comment: There is no difference. Threads are the same, whether they're run on the CPU or GPU.